# Шаблонные классы и функции

Tags: c#

Предположим, имеется следующая структура классов:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> where T : ISomeInterface
{
    public abstract T AbstractMethod();
}

public class Child : AbstractClass<ISomeInterfaceImplementation> 
{
    public override ISomeInterfaceImplementation AbstractMethod() { }
}

public class ChildTwo : AbstractClass<ISomeInterfaceImplementationTwo> 
{
    public override ISomeInterfaceImplementationTwo AbstractMethod() { }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly SomeType _someType;

    public ISomeInterfaceImplementation SomeMethod()
    {
        return new Child(_someType).AbstractMethod();
    }
    public ISomeInterfaceImplementationTwo SomeMethodTwo()
    {
        return new ChildTwo(_someType).AbstractMethod();
    }
}
```

В классе `SomeClass` отчётливо видно повторение кода, и хотелось бы написать что-то похожее на это:

```
public ISomeInterface SomeMethod<TAbstractClassChild>()
    where TAbstractClassChild : AbstractClass<ISomeInterface>
{
    return (TAbstractClassChild)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TAbstractChild), _someType).AbstractMethod();
}
```

Для того, чтобы потом можно было просто написать `new SomeClass().SomeMethod<Child>();` и `new SomeClass().SomeMethod<ChildTwo>();` и так далее, вместо

```
var someClass = new SomeClass();
var sm = someClass.SomeMethod();
var smTwo = someClass.SomeMethodTwo();
```

Понимаю, что я где-то близко, но не получается, запутался. Подскажите, как исправить код, либо структуру классов, чтобы можно было это получить.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то например так:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public ISomeInterface SomeMethod<T, C>()
            where C : ISomeInterface
            where T : AbstractClass<C>, new()
    {
        return new T().AbstractMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Забыл добавить, там есть аргументы у конструктора. И метод с двумя параметрами уже теряет свою актуальность, потому что будет невозможно догадаться что должно выступать в роли парамера C.

Comment: @CRRRRRRRRASH: А, ну если есть параметры у конструктора, то нужна рефлексия. А откуда доставать значения аргументов?

Comment: Да, многое я забыл написать в вопросе. Но не могу найти как его редактировать.
В классе SomeClass уже есть приватное поле, которое будет передаваться в конструктор, что-то типо ```private readonly SomeType _someType```.

Comment: @CRRRRRRRRASH: Под вопросом есть ссылка «править» :)

Comment: Да, спасибо, отредактировал.